# Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Countries'. The duplicate key value is (1)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to copy data from one table to another and i get the error Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Countries'. The duplicate key value is (1). I understand what this means, but how do i remove it?
This is my sql server query:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[countries] ON
    ----Create TestTable
    CREATE TABLE TestTable (FirstName VARCHAR(100), LastName VARCHAR(100))
    ----INSERT INTO TestTable using SELECT
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Countries] (countryID, countryName)
    SELECT countryId, countryName
    FROM [dbo].[Sheet1]
    ----Verify that Data in TestTable
    SELECT countryID, countryName
    FROM [dbo].[Countries]
    ----Clean Up Database
    DROP TABLE TestTable
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[countries] OFF
```

The error message is:

```
Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 6
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Countries'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Countries'. The duplicate key value is (1).
The statement has been terminated.

(26 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: how could the source table have a duplicate ID to begin with?

Comment: Run the select on its own and see if the duplicate is there or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Countries] (countryID, countryName)
SELECT countryId, countryName
FROM [dbo].Sheet1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM [dbo].[Countries]
                  WHERE Sheet1.countryId = [Countries].countryID)
```

And since you are inserting into an Identity field I would also execute the following lines of code once I am done inserting data

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[dbo].[Countries]', RESEED, 0)
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[dbo].[Countries]', RESEED)
GO
```

This will reseed the identity value to next highest available identity value, otherwise you might get duplicate errors when Identity column tries to generate an identity value that you have already explicitly inserted into identity column.

Comment: i get a red underline under Sheet1.countryId

Comment: red underline does not necessarily mean it will error out, it maybe because your local cache needs refreshing. execute the statement and see if it throws an error.

Comment: i get Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
The multi-part identifier "Sheet1.countryId" could not be bound.

Comment: Update your question with the statement you are executing also the schema of your tables. I cannot help you unless I have all of this information.